# Guava Function Composition

Tags: java, guava

I saw that there is a utility to create `Function<A,C>`, which is a composition of `Function<A,B>` and `Function<B,C>`

I have a similar, but a little bit different case.

My first Function is `valueOfFunction` that returns an enum based on a key in my `BO` class.

The secind Function calls a method on the Enum with a parameter, which is the `BO` object.

So it's not exactly `A->B->C`

Here's the Function:

```
private final static class RequestConvertor implements Function<CoreData, List<Request>> {
    private final static Function<String,RequestConvertorEnum> typeConvertor =  valueOfFunction(RequestConvertorEnum.class);

    @Override
    public List<Request> apply(CoreData coreData) {
        RequestConvertorEnum requestConvertorEnum = typeConvertor.apply(coreData.getType());
        return requestConvertorEnum.convertToRequests(coreData);
    }

}
```

Here's the method of the enum:

```
   private final List<Request> convertToRequests(CoreData coreData) {
        List<PropertyWrapper> properties = getProperties(coreData);
        if (properties.size() == 0) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Request request = new Request(coreData.getKey(), properties, new RequestMetaData(
                coreData.getFoo()));
        return newArrayList(request);
    }
```

Is there a nicer way to compose these two functions together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think usage of `valueOfFunction` is inappropriate in first place - you are using it **only** in another function (it's `private static` member) invoking `apply` method immediately. You should use good old `Enum.valueOf(String)` static method:

```
private final static class RequestConvertor 
        implements Function<CoreData, List<Request>> {
    @Override
    public List<Request> apply(CoreData coreData) {
        return RequestConvertorEnum.valueOf(coreData.getType())
                .convertToRequests(coreData);
    }
}
```

Note that supplying String that doesn't represent any of enum values throws `IllegalArgumentException`, but in your present code you have potential `NullPointerException` at runtime ([Enums.valueOfFunction returns null if the Enum constant does not exist](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#valueOfFunction%28java.lang.Class%29)) and I suppose you are aware of it (if you weren't, you are now :)).

Moreover few suggestions about rest of code. If you don't need mutability, use [ImmutableLists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) instead of ArrayLists (I assume you don't modify result because `Collections.emptyList` is immutable itself so it will fail at runtime if you will modify result of `convertToRequests` method).

```
private final ImmutableList<Request> convertToRequests(CoreData coreData) { // 1.
    List<PropertyWrapper> properties = getProperties(coreData);
    if (properties.size() == 0) {
        return ImmutableList.of(); // 2.
    }
    Request request = new Request(coreData.getKey(), properties, 
            new RequestMetaData(coreData.getFoo()));

    return ImmutableList.of(request); // 3.
}
```

Some explanations:

1. Use ImmutableList as return type to guarantee behavior (immutablility).
2. Return empty immutable list, but [better than JDK's one](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/TenThingsAboutImmutableCollections).
3. Same as 2. but singleton immutable list here.

In case you need mutability, replace ImmutableList.of with Lists.newArrayList and leave method signature intact.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the possible exceptions in converting to Enum. The type as string is something we have when getting form the DB, and I prefer to pass it on and convert to Enum only when needed. Thanks for the inputs about collection. I think we can use the immutable list.

Comment: String -> Enum constant will we done only when needed in `RequestConvertor`'s apply method in both versions - your will invoke `valueOfFunction.apply` method and mine will invoke `Enum.valueOf` static method instead without creating second Function object.